# svn new repo error : 'URL when it should be a local path'

Tags: windows, svn

I have a existing set of repositories at 'http://123.456/subversion/'
I want to create a new repo with name MarketPlace.
On command line I did the following command.
I get the error 'URL when it should be a local path'
how do i resolve it?

```
svnadmin create http://123.456/subversion/MarketPlace/

svnadmin: E205000: 'http://123.456/subversion/MarketPlace' is a 
URL when it should be a local path
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the documentation on the [`svnadmin create`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.create.html) and the wording of the error, please. It says `... is a URL when it should be a local path`.

The `svnadmin create` tool creates a new local repository. The tool **accepts local path only** and does not accept HTTP(S) URLs.

Answer (score 0):

I tried `svnadmin create MarketPlace`   it showed no success/error reply.
When I typed 'http://123.456/subversion' in the internet browser,  I didn't see MarketPlace folder created.

I ended up using `SmartSVN Professional 9.2.2 UI tool` to create it fast.

*** I will still like to know why